# Is thermal (Johnson) noise intrinsically stochastic?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, noise

Thermal (Johnson) noise is caused by electron collitions. Since movement of electrons is intrinsically stochastic according to Quantum Mechanics (assuming the Copenaghen interpretation), does this mean that termal noise is intrinsically stochastic as well?

I found some similar questions in the forum, but the answers are sometimes contradictory. Sometimes people argues that it can be modelled with statistical mechanics, but this is just an aproximation that allows you to obtain average propeties (like average disspation power, average voltage). What I want to know is if the instananeous  shape of the noise is determined given initial conditions of the electrons, or if only the probabilities are determined and the outcomes are intrinsically random (again, assuming Copenaghen).